# Linear minimization program with ZIMPL

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, minimization, scip

I am trying to make a linear minimization program with ZIMPL. In principle, I must have a minimum number of configurations for each class. Knowing that I have six classes, don't I normally have to get 6 results as output?

But when I do it makes me minimize the last value against x6, but when I try to maximize it gives me the 6 values.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, you are asking why you sometimes don't get the values for all variables as an output? This can be answered easily: variables which have a value of 0 are typically omitted when printing the solution. So all variables that are not listed should have value 0 in the optimal solution computed by the solver.

Comment: Glad that I could help. If this answered your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to program with zimpl, I use this command to read a colone from a file: set L: = {read "file3.txt" as "<2n>"};
do print L;
but I find that if there is a value that will repeat to ,it will appear only once.
Can someone help me to have the display of all values even if they repeat.
thank you

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you might try to use 'param' instead of 'set'. A set is a mathematical set and this can contain each value just once.